# Cannot compile PDF more than 2

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I am still in learning on doing php coding and now,I am facing a problem. Here is a php coding to compile up to four PDF files into a single PDF but no matter how many files I put in it will only compile 2 files. Could anyone help me see where is the problem as I need to pass up this project pretty soon.
It will be a big help if some let me know where I should change.

Here is the coding:

```
<?php 

include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$uploaddir = "upload/uploaded/";  //set this to where your files should be uploaded.  
$i = 1;
$j = 1;

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) { 


    foreach($_FILES['file']['type'] as $key => $value) { 

    $ispdf = end(explode(".",$_FILES['file']['name'][$key]));  //make sure it's a PDF file     
    $ispdf = strtolower($ispdf); 

        if ($value && $ispdf=='pdf') { 
            //upload each file to the server 
            $filename = $i . '.' . 'pdf'; 
            $filename = str_replace(" ","",$filename); //remove spaces from file name 
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename; 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], $uploadfile); 
            $i++;
            $j++; 
        } 

    } 

    if ($j = 2) {
        goto first;
    }

    else {
        if ($j = 3) {
           goto second;
        }

        else {
        goto third;
        }
    }   




first:  
$pdf->addPDF('upload/uploaded/1.pdf')
    ->addPDF('upload/uploaded/2.pdf')
    ->merge('download', 'compiler.pdf');
    goto end;   

second:
$pdf->addPDF('upload/uploaded/1.pdf')
    ->addPDF('upload/uploaded/2.pdf')
    ->addPDF('upload/uploaded/3.pdf')
    ->merge('download', 'compiler.pdf');
    goto end;   

third:
$pdf->addPDF('upload/uploaded/1.pdf')
            ->addPDF('upload/uploaded/2.pdf')
            ->addPDF('upload/uploaded/3.pdf')
            ->addPDF('upload/uploaded/4.pdf')
            ->merge('download', 'compiler.pdf');
        goto end;   
}

end:
$myFile = "upload/uploaded/1.pdf";
unlink($myFile);

$myFile = "upload/uploaded/2.pdf";
unlink($myFile);

$myFile = "upload/uploaded/3.pdf";
unlink($myFile);

$myFile = "upload/uploaded/4.pdf";
unlink($myFile);

?>
```

Comment: I haven't seen anyone use `goto` in a long while. I'm not sure that using `end` as a label is a really good idea, since it it used as a part of PHP's language. I'd rather recommend doing this in a loop over 1 to n.

Comment: The reason for your problem is that you use a single `=` operator (variable assignment), not a `==` (comparison operator) in your if statements. A rather common typo. It will always return `true`, 'cause var assignment seldom fails. So you will always jump to first.

Comment: @some-no-descript-user Can you show me? and I have change the operator but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for($n = 1; $n =< $j; $n++){
    $pdf->addPDF('upload/uploaded/' . $n . '.pdf');
}
$pdf->merge('download', 'compiler.pdf');
```

Leave out the whole `if($j == 2){}` etc. block.

Comment: I try it but this error keep happening
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$n' (T_VARIABLE)
$pdf->addPDF('upload/uploaded/' $n . '.' . 'pdf');

Comment: Yes. There was a small typo. Forgot a `.` (concatenation operator) before `$n`.